# data-loading-text not working

Tags: javascript, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I want have have a "`Loading. . .`" whenever I click on the "`Submit`" button. In this case, how come it did not display the "`Loading. . .`" thingy? bootstrap 2.3.2

```
<input type="submit" data-loading-text="Loading..." disabled="disabled" style="" id="save" class="btn btn-primary " value="Submit" name="save">
```

Here's my JS:

```
$('#save').click(function() {
    var btn = $(this);
    btn.button('loading');
    btn.button('reset');
});
```

I can't find any error in console either. What did I miss?

Comment: `.button`? .. Sounds interesting..! perhaps you wanted `.val()` instead? Also, this is a submit, you should prevent it's default value, else it will reload the document! ;) Something like that? http://jsfiddle.net/cmfc6qLL/ (the setTimeout is just for an example purpose, some kind of delay to show that both "loading" and "reset" are written)

Comment: .val() works. Thanks!

Comment: despite the official documentation talks about "button.js" (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/) I would rather recommend use to use some pure jQuery solutions for such problems, it is just enough ;)

Comment: you will never see the word 'loading', as you're also immediately changing it to 'reset'... Perhaps you want to do something before changing it to 'reset'?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```js
$('#save').click(function() {
      var btn = $(this);
      btn.val(btn.data("loading-text")); setTimeout(function() {
          btn.val('reset');
        }, 2000);
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" data-loading-text="Loading..." style="" id="save" class="btn btn-primary " value="Submit" name="save">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example, you need to `btn.val('loading...');` because you change the value of your `input`. Here's a working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h8ntoewf/1).